# Running exe file in background in windows 10

Tags: exe, startup

How do I run an "exe" file on start up and in background?

I tried keeping the file in `shell:startup` folder but when it runs, the icon appears in taskbar which I don't want. How do I get rid of that icon in taskbar? Basically, I want to run the app in background.

Comment: Create a console application. In properties menu, change the application type from Console to Windows Form. If you start the application there will be no console or other window in taskbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make easily a service out of it using the [Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://nssm.cc/download)

It can be used as commonad-line tool and it has a graphical user interface.

In the System services you can start/stop the service and make it run mode Automatic